# Issues with row separation in powershell for excel

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting

I am looking for some assistance with separating computer names with an empty row in a powershell script. I currently have the script needed to convert my .csv to .xlsx. Please help.

1. Command to separate the computer name value in row 1 with an empty row.

I would really appreciate any help, even a link to explain how to format and do it.

This is currently what I am working with via Powershell. However, the output is not spacing the information out as the command seems to imply it should do.

```
### Set input and output path $inputCSV = "C:\nec\combinedfile.csv" $outputXLSX = "C:\nec\output.xlsx"

### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application  $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1) $worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)

### Build the QueryTables.Add command
### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel $TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV) $Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1")) $query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

### Set the delimiter (, or ;) according to your regional settings $query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

### Set the format to delimited and text for every column
### A trick to create an array of 2s is used with the preceding comma $query.TextFileParseType  = 1 $query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count $query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

# Get the last row in the worksheet $lastRow = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

# Specify the column where you want to check for changes (e.g., column A) $columnToCheck = 1

# Iterate through rows and insert a blank row when the value changes for ($row = $lastRow; $row -gt 2; $row--) {
    $currentValue = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row, $columnToCheck).Value
    $previousValue = $worksheet.Cells.Item($row - 1, $columnToCheck).Value

    if ($currentValue -ne $previousValue) {
        $worksheet.Rows.Item($row).Insert()
    } }

### Execute & delete the import query $query.Refresh() $query.Delete()

### Save & close the Workbook as XLSX. Change the output extension for Excel 2003 $Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,51) $excel.Quit()
```

However, it is doing this.
https://imgur.com/a/kdK2EQR

Comment: Have you considered using the great module from Doug Finke [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel)? That would make your life way easier. 

Comment: I just need to figure out where on that line is causing the issue to not add the line. Working with some restricted parameters.

Comment: Can anyone help me take a stab at this?

Comment: I don't know how others think about but I didn't get **AT ALL** what your issue actually is. You may share some sample input data and the expected output - posted as plain text, formatted as code - to support your explanation.